# When I use insert, update(DML statements) in mybatis, how can I be sure that they are executed successfully?

Tags: java, spring, mybatis

#### I have seen two common ways

one checks return like this

```
int returnCount = userMapper.insert(user);
if (returnCount == 0) {
    return "insert fails";
}
```

another way checks if function throws exception

```
try {
    userMapper.insert(user);
} catch (Exception e) {
    return "insert fails";
}
```

Actually, it also confused me when I study PrepareStatement executeUpdate method in JDBC.
In my view, if a method like that executed successfully, it returns a int value(no matter if it equals zero),or it will throw exception, but I'm not sure for that.

Comment: I think you generally want to use both approaches together.  You want to check whatever is returned and get any info you can from that, but then it's always good to wrap a try/catch around your code.  If you have an exception thrown, you obviously will want to deal with that too.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comment above, I just figured it out.I read some other blogs and thought about the comment carefully.Actually, success is a very subjective concept. A statement may execute normally(which means no exception thrown), it also can be unsuccess if the result does not meet our expectation(like updating a record that we thought existed but did not actually exist).That's why we check returns.